# How to get the absolute path of asset folder?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have folder named 'auto' inside the assets folder. I am working on running php script.

Here I have given absolute path for run.php.

My question is how to call assets folder

```
 $phpScript = Helpers::joinPath(
            "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project_name\\assets\\auto\\task", 
            "run.php "
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an asset path helper, but you can use `base_path('assets/foo/bar')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the absolute path for files located in the `public` folder using :
`$path = public_path("assets/auto/task/run.php")`

Comment: Yes, this works. Very helpful with Snappy to generate a pdf with an image

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.8 (don't know same applies to 5.x) there's a helper method to get the asset folder:

```
// $url = 'http://project_name.com/asset/auto/task/run.php'

$url = asset('auto/task/run.php');
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but your question is how to call assets folder. And the answer is to use the `asset()` helper.

This will generate the asset's url based on what you've assigned `ASSET_URL` to in the `.env` file.

You can read more in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 0):

$url = base_path('assets/auto/task/run.php')

use this hope helpful for you